# With python 3, what is the fattest way to find biggest digit in a string?

Tags: string, performance, large-data, digits

I am working with SMILES, a string representation of molecules, which uses matching pairs of digits to represents rings. I am working with a relatively large dataset, 1,9 Millions strings, for which i have a data augmentation procedure (SMILES randomisation) that can find up to 30 thousands unique equivalent SMILES (=string) per original SMILES. I end up with a very large number of string to test (a little bit below 100 billions). I want the fastest way to find the biggest digit used in a SMILES (string).
Some SMILES feature to consider as potential edge cases:  the digit "0" is always excluded and so far i have not found digits above 6 but it can theoretically go up to 9. Some SMILES (string) can have no rings so no digits

I have tried the  2 following functions :

```
def find_biggest_digits_1(smiles=str()):
    """
    find the biggest digits by iterating throught SMILES, test if character is digits then type cast as integer and check if bigger than previous then max digits
    """
    ### instantiate local variable
    max_digit=0 

    ### iterate through SMILES

    for character in smiles:
        if character.isdigit():
            digit= int(character)
            if digit > max_digit:
                max_digit= digit
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    
    return max_digit
```

```
def find_biggest_digits_2(smiles=str()):
    """
    find the biggest digits by iterating throught possible max digit possible and test if corresponding character is found in string
    """
    ### instantiate local variable
    max_digit=0 

    ### iterate through max digits possible solution
    for i in range(1,10):
        digit=10-i
        if smiles.find(str(digit))!=-1:
            max_digit=digit
            break
        else:
            pass
    
    return max_digit
```

when I take a random SMILES from my dataset i have the following results :

```
%%timeit
find_biggest_digits_1(smiles="COC(=O)c1cc(NC(=O)Nc2cnNc2)c(F)cc1F")
```

2.14 µs ± 64 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%%timeit
find_biggest_digits_2(smiles="COC(=O)c1cc(NC(=O)Nc2cnNc2)c(F)cc1F")
```

1.96 µs ± 78.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Function 2 is a bit faster then function 1 and this was more or less confirmed when i used multiprocessing on the whole datastet without the data augmentation procedure ( 1.9 millions string). For the bravest souls that want to reproduce the multiprocessing  I used 10 cores and the concatenation of train ,test and scaffold_test datasets from MOSES (https://github.com/molecularsets/moses)

```
%%timeit
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-2) as pool:
    results= pool.map(find_biggest_digits_1,df["sanitized_smiles"])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

1.37 s ± 69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%%timeit
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-2) as pool:
    results= pool.map(find_biggest_digits_2,df["sanitized_smiles"])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

1.34 s ± 50.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Edit solutions from answer:

```
def find_biggest_digits_1_b(smiles=str()):
    """
    find the biggest digits by iterating throught SMILES, test if character is digits then type cast as integer and check if bigger than previous then max digits
    """
    ### instantiate local variable
    max_digit=0 

    ### iterate through SMILES

    for character in smiles:
        if character.isdigit():
            digit= int(character)
            if digit > max_digit:
                max_digit= digit
                if digit>=9:
                    break
     
    return max_digit
```

test with random SMILES :

```
%%timeit
find_biggest_digits_1_b(smiles="COC(=O)c1cc(NC(=O)Nc2cnNc2)c(F)cc1F")
```

2.12 µs ± 30.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

multiprocessing with 1.9 millions string:
1.42 s ± 77.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Probably faster for edge case but similar performance overall than original solution

Second solution proposed:

```
def find_biggest_digits_3(smiles=str()):
    """
    find the biggest digits by using list/tuple comprehension with try and except for no ring (digit) in smiles 
    """
    try :
       return max(c for c in smiles if c.isdigit())
    except:
        return 0
```

test:
random smiles(same then before) :
2.51 µs ± 83.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
multiprocessing with 1.9 millions string:
1.5 s ± 92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

The solution is more concise but is a bit slower then other solution

Comment: Solution 1 can be much faster: remove the `else`/`pass` statements, and use a `break;` when `max_digit >= 9`, after confirming `digit > max_digit`. This means at _worst_, solution 1 iterates the whole string, but now it will stop when it found the highest possible. Solution 2 can be faster if you do it in reverse: start at 9, and work backwards. This way solution 2 can also finish early in some respects, but you still may end up iterating the string multiple times. I would expect with these changes that solution 1 would be faster, since both traverse the same distance for `max_digit`.

Comment: I think a simpler implementation of `find_biggest_digit` is `max(c for c in smiles if c.isdigit())`. You'd wrap that in a try/except block to catch the ValueError when there are no digits.

Comment: I have tested both solution and found that for the first one it performs globally the same and for the second solution it is more concise but a bit slower